# How to rotate imageView with scaling in infinite loop

Tags: uiimageview, swift4, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to rotate imageView with scaling in infinite loop.
Eg. ImageView will rotate in infinite loop and also will scale from 1.0 to 0.5 then 0.5 to 1.0 in a loop.

But not able to achieve it with my below code

```
func rotateViewWith(duration: Double = 1.0) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        }) { finished in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
                self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            }) { finished in
                self.rotateViewWith(duration: duration)
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help how to do it. And also how can I reset it on any button click.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use keyframes you can do a repeating animation. Something of this form

```
func rotateViewWith(duration: Double = 1.0) {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration:duration, delay:0.0, options:.`repeat`, animations:{
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.0, animations: { 
            self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: 0.0)
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
            self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
            self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        })
    })
}
```

You can stop it by calling

```
self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working. This only animate scaling from 1.0 to 0.5 then 0.5 to 1.0 in loop but no rotation.

Comment: @AsifRaza, because you options should looks like: [.repeat, .autoreverse]